# Microsoft Graph "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again" in WEBDEV

Tags: api, authentication, calendar, calendarview, windev

The code below is used to get calendar from my email account through Microsoft Graph. But I keep getting an error. I can get the list of places and user information, but I can´t get the calendar.

I´ve tried this code:

CODE :

```
gsO365_ClientID                 est une chaîne  = "..."
gsO365_ClientSecret             est une chaîne  = ".."
dGdO365_ClientSecret_Expiration                 est une Date    = ".."
gsO365_Tenant                   est une chaîne  = ".."
gsO365_URICallBack_WEB                  est une chaîne  = "http://localhost/inscription/WD260AWP/WD260Awp.exe/OAUTH2_RETOUR"
gsO365_URICallBack_WEB_Test             est une chaîne  = "http://localhost/WD250AWP/WD250Awp.exe/OAUTH2_RETOUR"
sGsO365_URICallBack_APP                 est une chaîne  = ".."

OAuth2Params est OAuth2Paramètres
OAuth2Params..ClientID                  = gsO365_ClientID
OAuth2Params..URLAuth                   = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[%gsO365_Tenant%]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize"
OAuth2Params..URLToken                  = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/[%gsO365_Tenant%]/oauth2/v2.0/token"
OAuth2Params..ParamètresSupplémentaires = "force_reapprove=false"
OAuth2Params..Scope                     = "offline_access Calendars.Read"
MonToken est un AuthToken               = AuthIdentifie(OAuth2Params)
        
oRequête                        est une httpRequête
oRequête.Méthode        = httpGet
oRequête.URL            = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events"
oRequête.ContentType            = "application/json"
oRequête.AuthToken      = MonToken
Réponse                     est une httpRéponse
jsRéponse                   est un JSON
Réponse                         = HTTPEnvoie(oRequête)
SI ErreurDétectée ALORS
    Erreur("La requête HTTP à Office 365 a échouée"+RC+ErreurInfo())
    RENVOYER Faux
SINON
    jsRéponse = Réponse..Contenu
    Trace(Réponse..Contenu)
// Le serveur a renvoyé une erreur
SI jsRéponse.Error..Existe ALORS
    Erreur("La requête à Office 365 a échouée"+RC+jsRéponse.Error.Message)
SINON
        Trace(jsRéponse)
FIN
FIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you add the follow autorisations on the API permissions page :

Calendars.Read, Calendars.ReadWrite